# How to call asynchronous method recursively with different parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, protractor, es6-promise

I have a method of rest call using request module  which is `restRequest()` which returns response as promise which is asynchronous method, I have to call this method recursively with different parameters after getting the each results and passing that result to same method.

Example code:

```
restRequest(url, "POST").then(function(response) {
   restRequest(secondUrl, 'GET', response).then(function(response2) {

   }):
});
```

will this works, or any other things are there to solve this one.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) library for this

Specifically the `waterfall`

Which would work like

```
async.waterfall([
    function firstRequest(callback) {

         restRequest(url, "POST").then(function(response) {
               callback(null, response);
         });
    },
    function secondRequest (data, callback) {
         restRequest(secondUrl, 'GET', data).then(function(response2) {
               callback();
         });
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // Handle err or result
});
```

Sorry for formatting I'm on mobile.

You can read about how async.waterfall works from the link above.

Your method works but depending on how many requests you have you can end up with quite a deep callback hell

But since you are using promises you can just return your promise chain like

```
restRequest(url, "POST")
.then(function(resp) { 
    return restRequest(secondUrl, "GET", resp);
})
.then(function(resp) {
    return restRequest(thirdUrl, "GET", resp);
});
.then(function(resp) {
    // do whatever keep the chain going or whatever 
})
.catch(function(error) {
     // if any of the promises error it will immediately call here. 
});
```

With promises you can return a new `promise` from within a `.then` and just keep the chain going infinitely.

I'm just biased for async as i think it really improves readability when used right.

Comment: thanks for the comment @datsik, i'll check and udate

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like:

```
let requestParams = [
  [url, 'POST'],
  [secondUrl, 'GET'],
  ...
];

function callRecursive(response){
  if(!requestParams.length) return Promise.resolve(response);
  let params = requestParams.shift();
  if(response)  params.push(response);
  return restRequest(...params).then(callRecursive);
}

callRecursive().then(successCallbk).catch(errCallBk);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply one or more arguments to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to your partially applied function.

```
restRequest(url,"POST").then(restRequest.bind(this,secondUrl, "GET"))
                       .then(restRequest.bind(this,thirdUrl, "GET"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these are fired off in serial, what you really have is a simple chain of functions (some return promises, some might not) that can compose (or sequence, here) together, which I find to be a neat way to isolate out everything you want to happen and then combine behaviors as needed. It's still a Promise chain under the hood, but expressed as a series. First, a few utility methods to help:

```
var curry = (f, ...args) => 
          (f.length <= args.length) ? f(...args) : (...more) => curry(f, ...args, ...more);
var pipeP = (...fnlist) =>
          acc => fnlist.reduce( (acc,fn) => acc.then(fn), Promise.resolve(acc));
```

then

```
//make restRequest only return a Promise once it's given its 3rd argument
var restRequest = autocurry(restRequest);

//define what our requests look like
var request1 = restRequest('firstUrl', "POST");//-> curried function, not yet called
var request2 = restRequest('secondUrl', 'GET');//-> curried function, not yet called

//define some simple methods to process responses
var extractURL = x => x.url;//-> simple function
var extractData = x=> x.data;//-> simple function

//final behaviors, i.e. do something with data or handle errors
//var handleData = ... //-> do something with "data"
//var handleError = ... //-> handle errors

//now, create a sort of lazy program chain waiting for a starting value
//that value is passed to request1 as its 3rd arg, starting things off
var handleARequest = pipeP(request1, extractURL, request2, extractData);

//and execute it as needed by passing it a starting request
handleARequest({postdata:5}).then(handleData).catch(handleErrors);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is the most obvious approach but it's not necessary. An alternative is to build a `.then()` chain by reducing an array of known parameters (urls and methods).

The process is presented [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) under "The Collection Kerfuffle".

```
function asyncSequence(params) {
    return params.reduce(function(promise, paramObj) {
        return promise.then(function(response) {
            return restRequest(paramObj.url, paramObj.method, response);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve(null)); // a promise resolved with the value to appear as `response` in the first iteration of the reduction.
}
```

This will cater for any number of requests, as determined by the length of the `params` array.

Call as follows :

```
var params = [
    {url:'path/1', method:'POST'},
    {url:'path/2', method:'GET'},
    {url:'path/3', method:'POST'}
];

asyncSequence(params).then(function(lastResponse) {
    //all successfully completed
}).catch(function(e) {
    // something went wrong
});
```